# Trying to push to Heroku -- Why am I getting this? ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.8.6

Tags: python, heroku

Very simple python app.  get this when trying to push to Heroku from git:

```
git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 38, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38/38), 21.09 KiB | 5.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 38 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.6
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.8.6 (from -r /tmp/build_006a9333/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-3.8.6 (from -r /tmp/build_006a9333/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
```

remote:  !     Push failed
remote: !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 09e26ac7b3791cd141f1df4ece7b18b6093229f8
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 09e26ac7b3791cd141f1df4ece7b18b6093229f8
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku :main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to peaceful-basin-40727.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-basin-40727.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-basin-40727.git'

Comment: If you read the error it seems to be saying you are trying to push the exact same code to heroku twice. Is this triggered by a heroku pipeline or are you manually pushing to heroku?

Comment: Did you add `python-3.8.6` into your `requirements.txt` file? That should be in the `runtime.txt` file

Comment: 1. I am pushing manually.  the error is because i have repeatedly tried.

Comment: yes, I have a requirements.txt file with "python-3.8.6" as the only plain text.

Comment: as @FalseDev said, the python version belongs into `runtime.txt`, see also [the heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes). 

`requirements.txt` is for the python packages you need.